# Is it possible to have characters instead of an icon in the notification bar or remove it?

Tags: android

Basically I would like to know if I can display numbers instead of an icon? I am creating a weather station app and would like to know if I can have the temperature display instead of an icon? Can I remove it?

Comment: should be possible if you can figure out a way to load numbers as images by simply creating a bitmap for the number at run time.

Comment: Ah that sounds interesting, so I would need to create a bitmap at run-time and simply add that. Let me google that.

Comment: After much searching and and reading, the simple answer seems no, you can't use a different icon every time the notification bar gets updated. The only way seems to be creating numbed icons from -50 till 50 so in effect 100 icons :( The **setSmallIcon(resourceID)** must accept a resource ID that points to an icon in the res folder. You can not dynamically update those Icons from what I have read. Someone please prove me incorrect.